# How to filter out periodic requests

Tags: python, django, openshift

[image]

I have a website that I have deployed on openshift.com, using django. Everytime it is requested I save the ip address and time of request to a table. I was looking at the table, and I see the above screenshot. I'm not sure exactly what is going on here. Obviously my site is getting pinged at 10 past the hour on the hour. I assume this is normal behaviour, based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27672042/http-method-head-on-my-openshift-server-received-every-hour. However I'd like to filter out these presumed requests from openshift so that I just see when the site is being requested by a user. Whats the best way to do this?

In django I am using:

```
def index(request):

    from ipware.ip import get_ip
    ip = get_ip(request)
    ....
    (save to table)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a table that has entries/ips you want to ignore.
or if you think it won't change much, just us a variable

```
def index(request):

    from ipware.ip import get_ip
    ip = get_ip(request)
    ....
    if ip not in LIST
        (save to table)
```

or you could use some filter logic on the dtabase/table (depending on what you are using to save the data?)